# How to run command line with QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

i have a application (X)Medcon, i want to run command line (convert file) with [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start-1). I tried but it is not success. This is my code

```
   convertDicomProcess = new QProcess(this);
   QString program = "C:\\Program Files\\XMedCon\\bin\\xmedcon.exe";
   QStringList arguments;
   arguments << "medcon"<< "-f" << "F:/33.nii" << "-c" << "dicom" << "-o" << "F:/33.dcm";

   convertDicomProcess->start(program, arguments);
   convertDicomProcess->waitForFinished();
   QByteArray output = convertDicomProcess->readAll();
   convertDicomProcess->close();
```

When i run command line with

> medcon -f E:\55.nii -c dicom -o
>   E:\55.dcm

it is convert success

Comment: chage to `arguments <<  "-f" << "F:\\33.nii" << "-c" << "dicom" << "-o" << "F:\\33.dcm";`
`

Comment: yes, thanks after remove aguments medcon it is working well

Answer (score 0):

If you path exists, I think you need to use quotes (\") in the string for the one:

```
QString program = "\"C:\\Program Files\\XMedCon\\bin\\xmedcon.exe\"";
...
```

Comment: okay, I i will try but I think string "C:\\Program Files\\XMedCon\\bin\\xmedcon.exe"; not problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "/c" << program << "-f" << "F:/33.nii" << "-c" << "dicom" << "-o" << "F:/33.dcm";

convertDicomProcess->start("cmd.exe", arguments);
```

Test if you really need "medcon" as an argument again, I do not know since I do not know the "medcon" program. If yes change it to:

```
arguments << "/c" << program << "medcon" << "-f" << "F:/33.nii" << "-c" << "dicom" << "-o" << "F:/33.dcm";
```

This code tries to run the medcon program in a shell.

Comment: I remove medcon argument so program working well, thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helps, please consider accepting/upvoting this answer so that this question is closed and potential other users with a similar problem find the solution